# Gridsplitter not showing nor working only when horizontal

Tags: c#, row, gridsplitter

I have a grid which simulates a print preview with some other features

```
<Grid Name="grdReport_RTF" Visibility="Visible">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtbReport" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10"  BorderBrush="Gray" Background="White" Foreground="Black" IsEnabled="True" Padding="10" Style="{DynamicResource rtbStyleDocLocal}" />

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="10" >
        ...
    </StackPanel>

    <TabControl Grid.Row="3" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="3" Margin="10">
        <TabItem Name="tbiReports" BorderBrush="Red" Background="Transparent" >
            <DataGrid Name="dtgReports" Background="Green" Height="100" Margin="10" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="tbiLastReport" BorderBrush="Red" Background="Transparent">
            <DataGrid Name="dtgLastReport" Background="Green" Height="100" Margin="10" />
        </TabItem>                      
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

So no matter what I try the gridspliter doesn't show nor work.

[image]

What's more I have taken off all the code below and put the one provided [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/gridsplitter/) and it stubbornly keeps on hiding

### Update

I've tried to simplify it all. In short:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="3" />
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="10"/>
<Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="Gainsboro"  BorderThickness="3"  />
</Grid>
```

works like a charm. Instead the following doesn't:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="3" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="10"/>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="Gainsboro"  BorderThickness="3"  />
</Grid>
```

What's wrong in that?

Comment: Did you try a different color to ensure it's not a visibility problem? Does the problem persist, if you replace your 1st, 3rd and 4th item by some simple placeholder control like `TextBox`?

Comment: You could inspect your application with something like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) in order to determine the actual visibility of the splitter.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I made the gridsplitter higher and changed the bg but nothing. Then I wrapped it in a coloured border and that showed up. But inside it nothing, not visible not working....

Comment: You need to stretch the splitter in width somehow... `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` or `Width="100"` Otherwise it won't be visible due to its non-existent size. I would be a bit surprised if thats the solution.

Comment: @grek40 Alas added Stretch and width but that didn't change a thing in horizonta. Works instead as i said in vertical

Comment: Your last example is working for me with `<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>` but has `ActualWidth="0"` by default. I also confirmed that the `ActualHeight` in your last working example is not zero, thats why it is working out of the box. If you have trouble with the resize direction (which I had when setting `Width="100"` instead of `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`) you can control it with `ResizeDirection="Rows"`

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO!  <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Width="100" ResizeDirection="Rows"/> Worked like a miracle. Please pls post it as a solution so that I can give you a trillion points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the `GridSplitter` element should chose its resize direction automatically based on its size proportions (up-down if `Height < Width` and left-right if `Width < Height`). For some reason, this logic may not apply and then the resize direction needs to be specified explicitely.

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="10" Width="100" ResizeDirection="Rows"/>
```

In this code, setting `Width` and `Height` ensures, that the splitter doesn't stay invisible due to zero size and `ResizeDirection` ensures, that the correct direction is supported.

Another property that may come handy is `ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"`, to ensure, that the right rows/columns are affected by the resize action.